# Jenkinsfile variable used in two separate stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job that uses two separate nodes (one for build, one for test), and I'd like to share a variable between two of these blocks of code in my `Jenkinsfile`. I assume it's possible, but I'm very new to groovy and the `Jenkinsfile` concept. Here is the relevant code so far:

```groovy
node('build') {
    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('Build') {
        bat(script: 'build')
        def rev = readFile('result')
    }
}

node('test') {
    stage('Test') {
            def SDK_VERSION = "5.0.0001.${rev}"
            bat "test.cmd ${env.BUILD_URL} ${SDK_VERSION}"
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'artifacts/**/*.xml'
            junit 'artifacts/**/*.xml'
       }
}
```

I want to assign the "rev" variable in the build stage, but then concatenate it to the SDK_VERSION variable in the Test stage. My error is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rev for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Comment: I guess you could simply define `rev` outside your `node` blocks with `def rev = ""`. Then it is in a global context and can be used inside your `node` blocks.

Comment: I was thinking there must be some way to make it global, but every time I looked it up, the resources all pointed to setting global Environment variables. I also just wanted to make sure I was using it correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just define the variable before your `node` block:

```
def rev = ''
node('build') {
  stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Build') {
    bat(script: 'build')
    rev = readFile('result')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In a declarative pipeline, @mkobit's answer won't work. You can, however, switchinto script mode explicitly and use its scoping, e.g. like so:

```
...
steps {
   script {
       def foo = sh script: "computeFoo", returnStdout: true

       node('name') {
           script {
               someStep()
           }
       }
    }
}
...
```